# Can't create GPU instances on GCE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to create a GPU instance (`n1-standard-2` with 1 NVIDIA T4 GPU) on Compute Engine and I have been getting this error since yesterday:

```
Operation type [insert] failed with message "The zone 'projects/deep-learning-xxxx/zones/us-central1-a' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later."
```

It seems that this region of Google Cloud doesn't have enough GPU resources, but I am getting the same error with other zones too, and after trying multiple times. Regular non-GPU instances are working fine though. I am trying to figure out if I'm doing something wrong or if there is a just a huge demand for GPU instances on GCP right now.

Comment: Have you checked your [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#gpu_quota)?

Comment: Correct. GPUs are rare resource (in the cloud, for gamers, for miners,...) and it's possible that you were at a very demanding time!

Comment: @ClarkMcCauley, yes, I added the required per-region quotas for GPUs and the global GPU quotas. It doesn't seem to be related to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reasons for GPU not being created on a VM in a particular region/zone can be,

1.Resource Unavailability. Check Resource availability here [GPU availability across regions and zones](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/gpu-regions-zones#gpu_regions_and_zones).

2.Quota overuse can restrict the creation of GPUs. Refer [Checking project quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#checking_project_quota) for details.

3.Few GCP Restrictions, you can refer to the list of [Restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus#restrictions) here.

You can Check GPU Quota in [Create VM with GPU's](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/create-vm-with-gpus)

Alternatively, GCP offers a feature called [Reserving Compute Engine zonal resources](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources) to ensure that your project has resources for future use.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I was able to launch a *preemptible* GPU instance without a problem. So it really seems like Google Cloud doesn't have enough GPU resources to reserve an on-demand GPU VM at the moment.